# how can you search for images/symbols in a pdf

Tags: image, pdf, search

I have a pdf which is a blueprint and I want to search for all occurences of a specific symbol (like lighting or exit signs). What's the best way to do this besides manually going through the drawing and counting the symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question. Here's a software that does just this: bluebeam.com/us/products/revu/search.asp

BlueBeam Revu is the software if the link is broken in the future. It allows you to make a rectangle around the image you would like to search for and finds all occurrences in the document of such symbol enclosed in that rectangle drawn.